# Terraform how to iterate through cloudinit user data block

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I want to spin up 2 ec2 instances with the tags **"ins-1"** and **"ins-2"**. Further, at the launch of both ins-1/ins-2 I want to set their hostnames to be of **"server-1"** and **"server-2"** with the use of cloudinit. Below code creates the 2 instances with the tags ins-1 and ins-2 perfectly well but both instances get the hostname **"server-1"**

```
variable "host_count" {
  default = "2"
}
variable "host_name_prefix" {
  default = "cluster-node-"
}
variable "aws_keypair_privatekey_filepath" {
  default = "../mykey.pem"
}


resource "aws_instance" "ins" {
  count = "${var.host_count}"
  ami       = "${lookup(var.AMIS, var.aws_region)}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.mypublic-1.id}"
  tags {
    Name = "server-${count.index + 1}"
  }
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.allow-ssh.id}"]
  user_data = "${data.template_cloudinit_config.example.rendered}"
  }


data "template_cloudinit_config" "example" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true
  # count = "${var.host_count}"

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = <<EOF
    preserve_hostname: false
    fqdn: "server-${count.index + 1}"
    hostname: "server-${count.index + 1}"
EOF
  }
}
```

Highly appreciate your feedback on this. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why have you commented out the `count` on the templated user data? From a quick look that plus changing your `user_data` to `${data.template_cloudinit_config.example.*.rendered[count.index]}` should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks so much @ydaetskcoR that was exacly what I needed. The reason for commenting out the count earlier was due to an error that was thrown however the user_data line didn't have the count.index specified correctly. Thanks once again. :)